# How can i save chat messages using js and json without refresh page?

Tags: javascript, json, janus

I'm using Janus textroom and I need to save messages in array or json, even if users refresh pages.I need it, because I cant do too much requests to server and save in database :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the local storage API

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)